# Antd Tree : I want to disable checking childs by default

Tags: reactjs, tree, antd

I'm using React with Antd and working with Tree Component, i have my Tree Data and I want to be able to check only parents, and when I check a parent all his child are checked also, but I don't want to be able to check only some child of a parent..
Can I disable checked feature on childs and display it only for parent ?

[This is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-4-18-9-forked-msrshe)

Thank you

Comment: Oups! i edit it :)

Comment: i think it working correctly, what is your exact question?

Comment: I want to disable checking childs, only parents can be checked/unchecked :)

Comment: is this help 
https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-4-18-9-forked-i52zr8?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

you have to add one property, `checkable: false` for the `children` nodes only, dont use for parent, to your data `treeData`,

```
const treeData = [
  {
    title: "0-0",
    key: "0-0",
    children: [
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-0-0",
        key: "0-0-0",
        children: [
          {
            title: "0-0-0-0",
            key: "0-0-0-0"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-0-1",
            key: "0-0-0-1"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-0-2",
            key: "0-0-0-2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-0-1",
        key: "0-0-1",
        children: [
          {
            title: "0-0-1-0",
            key: "0-0-1-0"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-1-1",
            key: "0-0-1-1"
          },
          {
            checkable: false,
            title: "0-0-1-2",
            key: "0-0-1-2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "0-0-2",
        key: "0-0-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "0-1",
    key: "0-1",
    children: [
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-1-0-0",
        key: "0-1-0-0"
      },
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-1-0-1",
        key: "0-1-0-1"
      },
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-1-0-2",
        key: "0-1-0-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "0-2",
    key: "0-2"
  }
];
```

working code https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-4-18-9-forked-i52zr8?file=/index.js

Comment: I should create a function that return me the new tree Data, have you an idea how to do it  please ?

Comment: @Ashish - seems like the hardcoded `checkable` to `false` is being set on nodes `0-0-0` and `0-0-1` - and these are parent-nodes which have children. I guess your intention was to hardcode it only on the leaf nodes (ie, nodes that do not have any children) - is that correct?