# Antd Tree, : how to Disable checking child by default

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array, antd

I working on a react project using Antd and I want to be able to disable cheking childs of my Tree component, so I can check only parent.[This is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-4-18-9-forked-mvbf90?file=/index.js)

I found that I can add checkable : false to my child but I must create a function that render me a new TreeData that I can use instead of my normal data so I've tried this :

```js
const TreeData = (data) => {
        data.map((category) => {
            category.children.map((family) => {
                family.children.map((table) => {
                    table.checkable = false;
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

But it return undefined when i'm console.log the data received..
So my question is : how to switch from this :

```js
const treeData = [
  {
    title: "0-0",
    key: "0-0",
    children: [
      {
        title: "0-0-0",
        key: "0-0-0",
        children: [
          {
            title: "0-0-0-0",
            key: "0-0-0-0"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-0-1",
            key: "0-0-0-1"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-0-2",
            key: "0-0-0-2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "0-0-1",
        key: "0-0-1",
        children: [
          {
            title: "0-0-1-0",
            key: "0-0-1-0"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-1-1",
            key: "0-0-1-1"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-1-2",
            key: "0-0-1-2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "0-0-2",
        key: "0-0-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "0-1",
    key: "0-1",
    children: [
      {
        title: "0-1-0-0",
        key: "0-1-0-0"
      },
      {
        title: "0-1-0-1",
        key: "0-1-0-1"
      },
      {
        title: "0-1-0-2",
        key: "0-1-0-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "0-2",
    key: "0-2"
  }
];
```

To this :

```js
const treeData = [
  {
    title: "0-0",
    key: "0-0",
    children: [
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-0-0",
        key: "0-0-0",
        children: [
          {
            title: "0-0-0-0",
            key: "0-0-0-0"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-0-1",
            key: "0-0-0-1"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-0-2",
            key: "0-0-0-2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-0-1",
        key: "0-0-1",
        children: [
          {
            title: "0-0-1-0",
            key: "0-0-1-0"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-1-1",
            key: "0-0-1-1"
          },
          {
            title: "0-0-1-2",
            key: "0-0-1-2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-0-2",
        key: "0-0-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "0-1",
    key: "0-1",
    children: [
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-1-0-0",
        key: "0-1-0-0"
      },
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-1-0-1",
        key: "0-1-0-1"
      },
      {
        checkable: false,
        title: "0-1-0-2",
        key: "0-1-0-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "0-2",
    key: "0-2"
  }
];
```

Without hardchanging the first data of my Tree.
Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why `checkable` is only set on the first-level children and not on next-level/s. For example `0-0-0` has `checkable` set to `false` - but not `0-0-0-0`. If this is indeed what is required, please try this: `const newTreeData = treeData.map(obj => ({...obj, children: obj.children.map(cObj => ({...cObj, checkable: false}))}));`

Comment: In the code-snippet shown in the question, there are multiple `.map` used; and it does not seem that any of those actually `return` anything. When using `.map()` to iterate over an array and using `{` & `}` to enclose the callback, one may need to `return` a desired transformation for each element. Please note that`.map()` does not (of & by itself) mutate the array on which it is used (to iterate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be one possible implementation to set `checkable` as `false` for the specific nodes described in this question:

```
  const makeUnCheckable = dataArr => (
    dataArr.map(
      obj => ({
        ...obj,
        children: obj?.children?.map(cObj => ({
          ...cObj,
          checkable: false
        }))
      })
    )
  );

  return (
    <Tree
      checkable
      onExpand={onExpand}
      expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
      autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
      onCheck={onCheck}
      checkedKeys={checkedKeys}
      onSelect={onSelect}
      selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
      treeData={makeUnCheckable(treeData)}
    />
  );
```

This is the result displayed on Codesandbox:

[image: Sample Results]

**NOTES**:

1. The elements showing as `checked` are clicked manually.
2. There is no `check` option for nodes `0-0-0`, `0-0-1`, `0-0-2`, `0-1-0-0`, `0-1-0-1`, `0-1-0-2` - which is the expected objective defined in the question under **To this**

**EDITED**:

On perusing [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71348453/13658816) it seems like OP requires something like this:

[image: Possible actually-desired objective]

(A tree where leaf nodes are uncheckable)

This may be achieved by a recursive method - something like this:

[image: Changes to code]

(Changes are present in: Lines 100 to 106. And line 118.)

**EDITED - 2**
Update based on comments below.
In order to identify the children for any given parent/key, something like the below may be useful:

[image: findKey and getChildren]

Two methods are here. One is `findKey` which is recursive and gets the object which has a particular `key` (say `0-0-1`). The other is to check if the object with the `key` has any `children` and if yes, return the `children` array.

Comment: It works! thank you, have you a good article on recursive method please ? :)

Comment: When i console.log the checked elements, there is no childs inside..have you an idea how to get it please ?

Comment: A) There is a ton of amazing reference materials for recursion. Personally, I would try starting from `factorial` (owing to my inclination towards mathematics). B) When I ran the code from the link (just now), the console at line 93: `console.log("onCheck", checkedKeysValue);`, shows checked-elements correctly. What you need is to traverse the tree to get the children for any given key.

Comment: Yes I'm trying, but I think I need another recursive method ^^', because I check only in the first level,Can you take a look please ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cjseuz?file=index.js

Comment: Edit : this is exactly what I'm looking for, the only change is to hide checking childs like what you showed me before, I'm working on it but If you want to get a look please :) 
Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-haibt-hjo4kf

Comment: It is not typical to provide step-by-step guidance on stackoverflow. I have created a new chat-room on stackoverflow [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242626/createnewtree). You should have access to this room. Will work on it as well and share updates on the chat.